# How to query a GET Request

Tags: express

I have the following working GET Request

```
//View Project
router.get('/viewproject', mid.requiresLogin, function(req, res, err){
  Project.findById({id: req.body.projectId}, function(err, Project){
      res.render('projects/viewproject', {project});
  });
});``
```

However this brings all the projects to view. I'm wanting to only view those projects created by the user in the logged in session. 
I have req.body.userName linked to the create project model and req.session.userId for the user's session, but i'm unsure how to connect them together to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: change req.body.projectId to req.query.projectId

Comment: can you provide the schema of Project collection?

Comment: Hi, thank you for a prompt response.